# Newer socket.io client not connecting to older socket.io server

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get a newer socket.io client to connect to a server process that is using an older version of socket.io, 0.9.14.  I've included a small example of both client and server to demonstrate this.  I know the easy answer is to upgrade the server to a newer socket.io version and that is being done.  But that will take some time and I'd like to see if there is something that I can do to make the client communicate successfully with the server without upgrading the server.  Ultimately I want an Android client to be able to connect but it's exhibiting similar connect issue as the simple nodejs client sample I've posted here.  I don't know it's identical but seems worthwhile to start with nodejs client for testing.

When the client connects it sees "connect sent", "finished emit", but doesn't get the server response message.  The server repeatedly shows the following message:  "info  - unhandled socket.io url".  This is repeated until the client is stopped.  If I update the server's package.json to use "1.3.5" for socket.io then the example works fine.

Client package.json

```
{
  "name": "ClientJS",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "client.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "dependencies": {
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "socket.io": "1.3.5",
    "socket.io-client": "1.3.5"
  }
}
```

client.js

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var serverUrl = 'http://localhost:3300';

var conn = io.connect(serverUrl);

console.log('connect sent');

conn.emit('join', 'default', function(resp, data) {
    console.log('server sent resp ' + resp + " " + data);
});

console.log('finished emit: join');
```

server package.json

```
{
  "name": "ServerJS",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.12.3",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "socket.io": "0.9.14"
  }
}
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

server.listen(3300);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, function() {
    console.log('listen callback was called');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('connection: event came in');
    socket.on('join', function(p1, fn) {
        console.log('client sent '+p1);
        fn(0, 'some data');
    });
});
```

As I mentioned my real goal is to get an Android client running against this server.  But I'm using a Nodejs client to make it easy to demonstrate the problem.  Does anyone know how to make this work that doesn't involve upgrading the server side to a newer socket.io?  Thanks.

Comment: How about you run your client with the older socket.io until the server is upgraded?  Not ideal, but then you run compatible clients and servers.

Comment: That is a good suggestion, but the reason for using newer socket.io on client side is to imitate the android environment.  I already tried using the earliest version of nkzawa's socket.io library and still doesn't work.  So I thought I'd concentrate on the newer version in nodejs first.

Comment: I can't find anything written about using new client library with old server library.  Do you know that the "express" part of your node server is working?  E.g. your web server is working successfully?

Comment: One thing I see with your client code is that you can't `conn.emit(...)` immediately after you call `io.connect()`.  You have to wait for the `'connect'` event to arrive back so you know the connection has completed before you send your first `.emit(...)`.

Comment: Yes, it is working.  We also have a web based client in the same server project that is working as it's using same socket.io version.  I was hoping for any hack to allow the android side to continue.  But if I have to wait fo the server to be upgraded I'll just have to be patient.

Comment: I commented out the emit on the client.js side.  Same result, older server side doesn't show a connection coming in but the newer version does.  Thanks for taking the time.